# Gmail oauth received on date using PHP

Tags: php, oauth, gmail-api

How do I go about getting a count of emails received on a particular date across all gmail folders.  Managed to get email inbox counting working ok but now need to figure out how to get number received  for previous day using PHP and oauth.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [messages#list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) method allows you to pass a `q` parameter which accepts the same query format from the Gmail search field.

Thus it's possible to do this:

```
// $gmail is an instance of Google_Service_Gmail
$messages = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', array(
    'q' => "after:2014/10/20 before:2014/10/21"
));

// $count is the number of messages from 2014/10/20
$count = $messages->getResultSizeEstimate();
```

Beware that the result will be different from what you see in Gmail if you have the 'Conversation view' turned on.